Cannot add Cocoapods plugin in KMM Project
So i want to initialize static framework for cocoapods in build.gradle but i cannot install cocoapods plugin
i got this error :

Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods',
version: '1.15.2']
> The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so
compatibility cannot be checked.

Here's the build.gradle :
import com.codingfeline.buildkonfig.compiler.FieldSpec.Type.STRING

plugins {
  kotlin("multiplatform")
  kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.23"
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods") version "1.15.2"
  id("com.android.library")
  id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.24-1.0.20"
  id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
  id("koin")
  id("com.rickclephas.kmp.nativecoroutines") version "0.13.3"
  id("dev.icerock.moko.kswift") version "0.6.0"
  id("com.codingfeline.buildkonfig") version "+"
  id("io.kotest.multiplatform") version "5.8.0"
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover") version "0.7.4"
  id("dev.icerock.mobile.multiplatform-resources")
}

val koinVersion = "3.1.4"

buildkonfig {
  packageName = "id.test.shared"
  objectName = "TestSharedConfig"
  exposeObjectWithName = "TestSharedPublicConfig"

  // default config is required
  defaultConfigs {
    buildConfigField(STRING, "APP_STORE_BASE_URL", "itunes.apple.com")
  }

  defaultConfigs("staging") {
    buildConfigField(STRING, "APP_STORE_BASE_URL", "itunes.apple.com")
  }

  defaultConfigs("production") {
  
    buildConfigField(STRING, "APP_STORE_BASE_URL", "itunes.apple.com")
  }
}

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
  iosX64()
  iosArm64()
  iosSimulatorArm64()



  targetHierarchy.default()

  androidTarget {
    compilations.all {
      kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
      }
    }
  }


  sourceSets {
    commonMain.dependencies {
      implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")
      implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.0")
      implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.4.0")
      implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koinVersion")
      implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:1.5.4")

      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:2.3.0")
      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:2.3.0")
      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:2.3.0")
      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:2.3.0")
      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:2.3.0")
      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-encoding:2.3.0")
      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:2.3.0")
      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.3.0")

      implementation("com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-no-arg:1.0.0-RC")
      implementation("co.touchlab:stately-isolate:1.2.2")

      api("co.touchlab:kermit:1.1.3")
      implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
      implementation("co.touchlab:stately-common:1.2.2")
      implementation("com.badoo.reaktive:reaktive:1.2.2")
      implementation("com.badoo.reaktive:reaktive-annotations:1.2.2")
      implementation("com.badoo.reaktive:coroutines-interop:1.2.2")

      api("dev.icerock.moko:resources:0.24.0-beta-4")
      api("dev.icerock.moko:resources-compose:0.24.0-beta-4") // for compose multiplatform
      implementation("dev.icerock.moko:resources-test:0.24.0-beta-4")

    }

    commonTest.dependencies {
      implementation(kotlin("test"))
      implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
      implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
      implementation("io.mockative:mockative:2.0.1")
      implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.7.0")
      implementation("io.kotest:kotest-framework-engine:5.8.0")
      runtimeOnly("io.kotest:kotest-framework-api-jvm:5.8.0")
      implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-test:$koinVersion")
      implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")
      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:2.3.0")
      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.3.0")
    }

    androidMain.dependencies {
      implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:1.5.4")
      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:2.3.0")
      implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0")
      implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.12.0")
      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:2.3.0")
    }

    iosMain.dependencies {
      implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:1.5.4")
      implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:2.3.0")
    }
  }
}

// add support for kotlin extension function and sealed class to enum swift
kswift {
  install(dev.icerock.moko.kswift.plugin.feature.SealedToSwiftEnumFeature)
  install(dev.icerock.moko.kswift.plugin.feature.PlatformExtensionFunctionsFeature)
}

android {
  compileSdk = 32
  namespace = "id.Test.shared"
  defaultConfig {
    minSdk = 23
    targetSdk = 32

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    testInstrumentationRunnerArguments["clearPackageData"] = "true"

    testOptions {
      execution = "ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR"
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
  }

  dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.4.0")
    androidTestUtil("androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.1")

    debugImplementation("com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:3.5.2")
    releaseImplementation("com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2")
  }
}

dependencies {
  configurations
    .filter { it.name.startsWith("ksp") && it.name.contains("Test") }
    .forEach {
      add(it.name, "io.mockative:mockative-processor:1.2.6")
    }
}

sqldelight {
  database("TestDB") {
    packageName = "id.Test.shared.cache"
    sourceFolders = listOf("sqldelight")
  }
}

multiplatformResources {
  resourcesPackage.set("id.test.shared")
  resourcesClassName.set("id.test.shared")
}


I am also facing the same problem for cocoapods, I need to add the google login using KMP for iOS side. Did you find out any solutions for this problem?

Where did you get this?
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods") version "1.15.2"

The CocoaPods plugin should be the same version as Kotlin.
Example from our KMP sample:
https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit/blob/main/shared/build.gradle.kts#L6
https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit/blob/main/gradle/libs.versions.toml#L98

sorry i think i did wrong with the version number but i already replace it with
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods") version "1.9.23" and still get issue
The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so compatibility cannot be checked.
